# how to find the total Number of top employers in Naukri by using Following command

Tags: java, xpath

I want the xpath count of all the Top Employers in the Naukri.com site.

I used.

StoreXpathCount

```
//h2[text()="Top Employers"]//following::text(),'banner'
```

In the above code i want the total number of xpaths which contain Banner text in their name.

But it is not working. Please help me out.

Comment: What is this site? Is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is not valid XPath syntax

```
//h2[text()="Top Employers"]//following::text(),'banner'
```

It looks like you want the following sibling `table`, so:

```
//h2[.="Top Employers"]/following-sibling::table[1]
```

**Note**: `//` operator means `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so you don't need it for the second step.

But your question was:

> I want the xpath count of all the Top
>   Employers

I guess that would be the count of `tr`:

```
count(//h2[.="Top Employers"]/following-sibling::table[1]/tr)
```

**Note**: The source it's not aviable so I couldn't check if `tbody` element was present in the source or added by browser.